# Magento 2.2.6: Product collection does not apply the filter

Tags: magento2, attributes, collection, jquery

**EDIT:**
I have seen that in magento 2 the ListProduct page is cached, for this reason once loaded it does not enter.

Is there any way to modify the query returned by ListProduct?

I extend the **class**:

> \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct

And the method:

> addAttributeToFilter

I do not apply the changes, when I look at the products that are inside the collection, they all come out to me.

If I get the query and use it in the sql server it shows me the well filtered products.

```
public function getLoadedProductCollection()
{

    $idCustomer = $this->getLoggedInCustomerId();

    if ($idCustomer) {
        $productCollection = $this->_getProductCollection();

        /**
         * items collection of table representative_brand
         */
        $brandCollection = $this->representativeBrandCollection;
        $brandCollection->addFieldToFilter(self::CUSTOMER_FIELD, $idCustomer); 

        $items = $brandCollection->toArray()['items'];

        $arr_groups = [];
        if (count($items) > 0) {
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $arr_groups[] =  $item[self::GROUP_FIELD];
            }
        }

        try {
            /**
             * attribute: sgi_itemgroup
             */
            $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(self::GROUP_ATTRIBUTE, ['in' => $arr_groups]);
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->logger->debug('Representative Brand: ' . $e);
        }


        var_dump($productCollection->toArray()); die("stop");

        return $productCollection;
    }

    return null;

}
```

Query of $productCollection:

> SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `at_sgi_itemgroup`.`value` AS `sgi_itemgroup` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='3' AND cat_index.is_parent=1 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = '1' INNER JOIN `search_tmp_5bb499868517e4_20951822` AS `search_result` ON e.entity_id = search_result.entity_id INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_sgi_itemgroup` ON (`at_sgi_itemgroup`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_sgi_itemgroup`.`attribute_id` = '205') AND (`at_sgi_itemgroup`.`store_id` = 0) WHERE (stock_status_index.stock_status = 1) AND (at_sgi_itemgroup.value IN('7', '7', '3')) ORDER BY `cat_index`.`position` asc, `cat_index`.`position` asc LIMIT 9

Comment: Have you found any error log?

Comment: No, no error, only the filter does not apply and it returns all the products of the category.

Comment: please try to print query         try {
            /**
             * attribute: sgi_itemgroup
             */
            $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(self::GROUP_ATTRIBUTE, ['in' => $arr_groups]);
print_r($productCollection->getSelect()->__toString());die("here);
        }
Query is right?

Comment: Yes, I have also done tests attacking the database and it returns the correct results.

Comment: Have you override this class using plugin?

Comment: No, just extends and di.xml preference

Answer (score 1):

For Magento 2, if you want to give custom conditions for product collection, your custom conditions works fine for your product collection in listing page but when you check for layered navigation in left sidebar,
You may have wrong result for product collection.

When you set custom conditions for product collection by before or after plugin for **getLoadedProductCollection()** or override php file, that print proper query for your result and when you check that query with a database you gave the proper result for a product.

In Magento 2 you need to override or create a plugin for build() function of IndexBuilder.php file from Catalog search module to accomplish your task.

Check blog for details instructions, [Set Custom conditions for product collection](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/apply-custom-conditions-for-product-collection-in-magento-2/)

You need to create module, to apply custom conditions to product collection and based on above blogs module you got a proper result for collection.

Refer blog and you got more idea for your issue, [Set Custom conditions in layered navigation](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/apply-custom-conditions-for-product-collection-in-magento-2/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in this method it is also cacheable, it is necessary that each time the request is made, the query is run as it filters by user id and each user has to see different products.